# Combining functions in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, functional-programming

How can I combine these similar function in Haskell?

```
getGroup [] acc = reverse acc
getGroup ((Letter x):letfs) acc = getGroup letfs ((Letter x):acc)
getGroup ((Group x):letfs) acc = getGroup letfs ((Group (makeList x)):acc)
getGroup ((Star x):letfs) acc = getGroup letfs ((Star (makeList x)):acc)
getGroup ((Plus x):letfs) acc = getGroup letfs ((Plus (makeList x)):acc)
getGroup ((Ques x):letfs) acc = getGroup letfs ((Ques (makeList x)):acc)
```

Letter, Group, Star, Plus and Ques are all part of a data type definition.

```
data MyData a 
        = Operand a 
        | Letter a
        | Star [RegEx a] 
        | Plus [RegEx a] 
        | Ques [RegEx a]
        | Pipe [RegEx a] [RegEx a]
        | Group [RegEx a]
        deriving Show
```

I wonder if there is a better way to write those function because of their similarities.
Mostly, I wish to combine the functions for Group, Star, Plus and Ques, because they are identical, but if there is a method to combine all of them it would be better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't get rid of the repetition of the pattern matching without using Template Haskell, which probably isn't worth it for only five different constructors. You can eliminate a lot of the other repetition though, and improve the performance characteristics of the function, as well.

```
getGroup = map go
  where go (Letter x) = Letter x
        go (Group x) = Group . makeList $ x
        go (Star x) = Star . makeList $ x
        go (Plus x) = Plus . makeList $ x
        go (Ques x) = Ques . makeList $ x
```

In addition to being much more concise, it also gets rid of the tail-recursion that will cause a space leak in a lazy language like Haskell.

Comment: sorry ... I'm new to Haskell. So my function Letter (for example) will actually become: `go ((Letter x):lefts) acc = getGroup lefts ((Letter x):acc)` ?

Comment: No, get rid of the accumulator. Tail recursion is bad when dealing with lazy evaluation; it will cause a space leak. It's better to use a higher order function like `map`, but if you are going to use explicit recursion, it should be like this `getGroup ((Letter x):lefts) = Letter x : getGroup lefts`.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `parse error on input `go'`, which is occuring at the second go: `getGroup = map go
  where 
 go ((Letter x):lefts) = Letter x : getGroup lefts
        go ((Star x):lefts) = (Star . makeList $ x) : getGroup lefts
        go ((Plus x):lefts) = (Plus . makeList $ x) : getGroup lefts
        go ((Ques x):lefts) = (Ques . makeList $ x) : getGroup lefts
  go ((Group x):lefts) = (Group . makeList $ x) : getGroup lefts` (so I supose the first one is ok).

Comment: Also, using explicit recursion seems to work :D, but it's still split into five functions.

Comment: Your code isn't indented properly. You probably have a mixture of tabs and spaces. Make sure that you are only using spaces and no tabs.

Comment: It's not split into five functions, it's a piecewise definition of a non-continuous function in five parts. I'll talk a bit more about an approach to making it more concise in an answer.

Comment: It seems that the error was due to the use of tabs instead of spaces. Thanks. Now I'm getting a new one of mismatched types: `Couldn't match type `[RegExp x0]' with `RegExp x0'
    Expected type: RegExp x0 -> RegExp x0
      Actual type: [RegExp x0] -> [RegExp x0]`
at `getGroup = map go`, the error being for "go". I believe it's because of `where go ((Letter x) : lefts) = Letter x : getGroup lefts etc`, where `((Letter x) : lefts)` is making a list of RegExp type.

Comment: Try copying the answer verbatim and manually from the reply and it should work. Your `go` definition is not the same one as in the answer.

Answer (score 4):

When you have a data type definition defined as you have, as a disjoint union of several different cases, you will inevitably end up with a large mess of case analysis in functions that process that type.

One approach to reducing the case analysis would be to simplify the base type by factoring out the commonality:

```
data MyData a = Val String a 
              | UnOp String [Regex a]
              | BinOp String [Regex a] [Regex a]
```

In this formulation, each case has a discriminator field with which you can tell apart the different kinds of each case. Here, I just used String assuming you'd give them names like "Operand", "Letter", "Star", etc., but you could also define separate enumeration types for the valid discriminators for kinds of `Val`, kinds of `UnOp`, etc.

The main thing you lose in this case is type safety; you could construct especially nonsensical things with the `String` fields as I gave them. A first approach to tackling this problem is to use what are known as *smart constructors*; these are functions with specifically-typed parameters that build the more weakly-typed core data in a type-safe manner. As long as you do not export the actual `MyData` constructors from your module, other users of your type will only be able to construct sensible data via your smart constructors.

If you want more guarantees of safe construction from the type constructors themselves, you would want to turn to the concepts of *Generalized Algebraic Data Types (GADTs)* and *Phantom Types*. The basic idea behind these is to have more flexible relationship between the type variables on the left-hand side of the `=` of a data type definition and the type variables on the right-hand side. They are a somewhat new and advanced feature of Haskell, though, so you may want to hold off on jumping into them until you have a firm grasp on standard Haskell data types.